# Query on a repeater date (acf)

Tags: php, posts, wp-query, custom-field, advanced-custom-fields

I'm struggling with this. I a have list of date (not fixed, I can have as many date as I want) made thanks to the ACF Repeater. In my query, I want to filter by date.

But, I have to hide some post if the date choosen is not between my 2 date fields (evenement_date_start and evenement_date_end). This is an example of my date list.

[image]

So if I choose between 01/10/2020 and 20/10/2020, the event should not show up. But right now, it does and I can't figure out why.

This is my query args, my date and variable have this format "Ymd" :

```
$args[] =
['relation' => 'OR',
    ['relation' => 'AND',
        [
            "key" => "evenements_liste_dates_AAA_evenement_date_start",
            "compare" => "<=",
            "type" => 'DATE',
            "value" => $startDate,
        ],
        [
            "key" => "evenements_liste_dates_AAA_evenement_date_end",
            "compare" => ">=",
            "type" => 'DATE',
            "value" => $endDate,
        ]
    ],
    ['relation' => 'OR',
        [
            "key" => "evenements_liste_dates_AAA_evenement_date_start",
            "compare" => "BETWEEN",
            "type" => 'DATE',
            "value" => [$startDate, $endDate],
        ],
        [
            "key" => "evenements_liste_dates_AAA_evenement_date_end",
            "compare" => "BETWEEN",
            "type" => 'DATE',
            "value" => [$startDate, $endDate],
        ]
    ],
];
```

And my post where rewriting

```
add_filter('posts_where', function ($query, WP_Query $wp_query) {
    if(!is_admin() && $wp_query->query_vars['post_type'] == "evenement" && !$wp_query->is_main_query()) {
        $query = str_replace("meta_key = 'evenements_liste_dates_AAA_evenement_date_start'", "meta_key LIKE 'evenements_liste_dates_%_evenement_date_start'", $query);
        $query = str_replace("meta_key = 'evenements_liste_dates_AAA_evenement_date_end'", "meta_key LIKE 'evenements_liste_dates_%_evenement_date_end'", $query);
    }
    return $query;
}, 10, 2);
```

Comment: ACF doesn't store dates as timestamps in the database - that's why your query isn't working as intended. If you edit the field to provide the "Return Format" as a MySQL Timestamp instead of any of their defaults, that should allow the query to work. Or alternatively, pull all events and then use PHP to identify whether each one qualifies before outputting it.

Comment: Hmm, as far as I know, you can choose the way the date is stored, but timestamp isn't in the choices availables

Comment: You'll need a MySQL friendly format or it won't work, keep in mind though that this will be a very expensive query, it will get more expensive/heavy/slow as the number of posts and meta increases. I would avoid using the `posts_where` approach

Comment: That's why I thought. But if I do this, I'll have to change all of the pagination, rewrite all of the structure of my code which is already very big... Thanks for your advices anyway